# Refine union of array types

Tags: flowtype

Is there a way to get Flow to refine a variable that is declared to be a union of array types (and not an array where the elements are a union type). For example, I tried the following code but it gave me errors (as indicated below):

```
function foo(arr: Array<string> | Array<number>): void {
  if (!arr.length) return;

  if (typeof arr[0] === 'string') {
    (arr: Array<string>); // error
  } else {
    (arr: Array<number>); // error
  }
}
```

[Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUBDATlgXIgQRwwE8AeAZyixjAHMA+RAH0OPLBAFsAjAUywMAlPgBucGABNEAbwBQiRDGCI0AQmxYAdABs+9KAAshiLHyggsYANwLEd5aqgkADnzgrNAbQAMAXUQAXmDEAHIqGnpQk3lFRUwcfCIsUkpqWkYhW0UAX0Q+HQo+WTt4zST2Mk5eAWFsxBy5RrkgA)